# Debugging SqlBulkCopy problems when it doesn't return any errors

Tags: c#, sqlbulkcopy

Right now my problem with sqlBulkCopy is that it finishes without any errors but when i look into the table i can't see any data.

The try catch block catches no errors and am i missing something? Because i don't see any problems with my code

This is the code i use:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Buying ID", typeof(string)));
table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Buying BPC ID", typeof(string)));
table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Buying BP Name", typeof(string)));
table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Buying BP Post Code", typeof(string)));
... snip ...
table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Buyer BP Type", typeof(string)));
table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Seller BP Type", typeof(string)));
table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("FileSource", typeof(string)));
table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ImportDate", typeof(System.DateTime)));

while ( (line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
{   
    string[] data = line.Split('\t');
    DataRow row = table.NewRow();
    for (int i=0; i<data.Length; i++)
    {
        row[i] = data[i];
    }
    row["FileSource"] = fi.Name;
    row["ImportDate"] = DateTime.Now;
}

try
{
    db.Connection.Open();
    SqlBulkCopy bulkcopy = new SqlBulkCopy(db.Connection);
    bulkcopy.BatchSize = 500;
    bulkcopy.BulkCopyTimeout = 600;
    bulkcopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.LNST_test";
    foreach (var col in table.Columns)
    {
        bulkcopy.ColumnMappings.Add(col.ToString(), col.ToString()); //col names in datatable are identical to col names in database
    }
    bulkcopy.WriteToServer(table);
    db.Connection.Close();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("ERROR : "+e.Message);
}
```

Comment: possibly a transaction issue? what is db?

Comment: Either transaction, or no rows in the table, or you're looking at the wrong table in SSMS.

Comment: database is MSSQL 2008, i am connecting to it as administrator (it's only a test database) and noone else. So i don't think it's a problem with transactions :(

Comment: I just did some work with bulk copy and had no problems .. +1 to see what the outcome is...please update if you find solution

Comment: of course i will post a update if i find a solution, it's very weird that i get no errors but no data appears in database

Comment: @usr there are only 4 tables in database, i don't think i misspelled the table name, or i'm looking into the wrong table

Comment: Can you hook up SQL Profiler? Please use the default template + Showplan XML. The latter will give you the execution plan for the bulk insert. Do you notice something unusual? Does the write actually happen? How many writes do you see in the writes column.

Comment: Next test you can run is to read the file 1000 times so you insert 1000 times the data. Is it quick or like nothing is happening at all?

Comment: @usr you were actualy right :D no rows in table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh god i'm stupid... i forgot this one line: `table.Rows.Add(row);`

I tried to insert an empty datatable. This is why i love stackoverflow, even if i don't get the answer from this avesome community, it helps me to solve my problems :D

Comment: I actually was suspicious if `NewRow` was enough but I'm not familiar with data tables :) Glad you found it.

Comment: yes this is the first time i use data tables and from other places i'm  got used to the thing, when you call NewRow() function it creates a new row and add it to the datatable and returns a pointer to the row so i can update the row :)

Comment: @ohigho_state of course, this was just a stupid error on my side :) but i will leave this question here when somebody makes the same error so he can figure it out :D